# OpenLayers 3: multi-color points

Tags: gis, openlayers-3

I found this **OpenLayers 3** example as a great basis for my project: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/igc.html

However, I would like to change one thing and I can't find out how to do it. When value of the input (under the map) is changed, red points appear on the tracks showing where each aircraft was at that time. I would like to have the red points to be of different colors for each track, so that it is easy to understand who is who. It can be the same array colors, or another array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use custom properties. It is possible to access them through `feature.get('name')` when rendering and then vary the color based on that.

Comment: Solved. It was a good idea. I created a featureOverlay after each feature has been created and read 'color' key of that feature. I added the 'color' key before hand as well. Thanks